# (python)Tensorflow Object Detection:How to visualize weights on advance model?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I follow sentdex's Tensorflow Object Detection Tutorial.
Reference website.... https://pythonprogramming.net/introduction-use-tensorflow-object-detection-api-tutorial/
I have successfully get the result.
Now I want to visualize weights after training.
Like this .... https://medium.com/@awjuliani/visualizing-neural-network-layer-activation-tensorflow-tutorial-d45f8bf7bbc4  ..or.. https://gist.github.com/kukuruza/03731dc494603ceab0c5 .. I try to get some weights information from model_ckpt_meta file. Model_ckpt_meta file has a lot of information, But I have no idea which one to choose. So I choose one of the information. And try visualize weights.
This is my code and result：

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
with tf.Session() as sess:
  new_saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph(checkpoint_path + '.meta')
  new_saver.restore(sess, tf.train.latest_checkpoint(checkpoint_path))
  weightArray=sess.run('BoxPredictor_5/ClassPredictor/weights:0')
  weightArray = weightArray.reshape(-1,1,32,3)
  x_min = np.min(weightArray)
  x_max = np.max(weightArray)
  wing=255.0*(weightArray.squeeze() - x_min) / (x_max - x_min)
  plt.imshow(wing.astype('uint8'))
  plt.axis('off')
```

[result:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oho8z.png)

Does the result has any way to show more clear?
If using ssd_mobilenet model can not get visualize weights.
Hope can tell me.
Many thanks.

Comment: Hello @Linminxiang, do you make it work?
I am working on this too.
Thank you!

Comment: Hi @Linminxiang , did you find a way to get the result ? I am working on a same thing.

Comment: @willSapgreen, any idea ?

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea.

Comment: No :( Still need to figure out how to do it.

Comment: any luck? Trying to do the same

Comment: Anyone achieved this? This may help: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/45889/extracting-the-feature-map-in-tensorflow-object-detection-api?newreg=3684f0c005d1428fa727b390c810a999